# Javascript- Adding data from HTML Table Rows in Form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I want to create a invoice form like When i click name input field then show popup table and control table rows by keyboard up and down arrow key and select a row by hit enter on keyboard.And final things is when i hit enter a row then Fill invoice form all fields.So how can i do that in JavaScript.

Form markup

```
<form class="data-form">
    <label>Name<input class="name" /></label>
    <label>Product id<input class="product-id" /></label>
    <label>Product Name<input class="product-name" /></label>
    <label>Product Price<input class="product-price" /></label>
</form>
```

Table markup:

```
<table class="data-table" id="test">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Product id</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
           <th>Jhon Deo</th>
           <th>2122</th>
           <th>Koke</th>
           <th>65</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th>Mark</th>
           <th>2123</th>
           <th>Chocolate</th>
           <th>70</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: I am not familiar with JavaScript in advance level  .So pls help me.

Comment: hello, I found a solution in [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/rotuni/2/edit?html,js,output). but the problem is here pass table data in JavaScript.But i want it in html. Thx @Nayak